# How to find equation from points

Tags: polynomials, coordinate-systems

I have a list of $218$ points. Is it possible to find an equation for a line that passes through the points?

**Update**: Is there a software that can generate the equation from the points?

Comment: If they all lie on a line exactly you only need two of those points.

Comment: If not all of them lie on the same line, you can get a line of "best fit"

Comment: You could also come up with a polynomial of degree at most 217 that passes through all of them.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation read this.

Comment: I have seen a plotted graph of the points, and they all lie on the same line (though not straight line).

Comment: Is there a software that does this?

Comment: I would imagine that matlab can do this. not sure though, try google?:p

Comment: @JoyceBabu Although I don't recommend it, you can even use microsoft excel to get a line of best fit for your data points

Comment: What's wrong with Excel?  It's going to calculate the same fit that every other software package does, using the same algorithm.

Comment: @Rustyn -- I second what Daniel wrote. Is there some problem with Excel? One problem (for some people) is that it costs money. Any other reason that you don't recommend it?

Comment: @bubba Eh, excel's pretty good. I was just worried that he'd have to manually type in his 218 data points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the points actually exactly lie on a line then just take the line through any of the two points.

If they only approximately lie on a line you probably want to do a linear regression.  You can read about it by Googling "linear regression," or you can just load the data up into your favorite spreadsheet, insert a graph, right-click on the graph or something, and tell it to show a best-fit line.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your update, I would suggest using SciPy's polyfit function (if what you're really looking for is a linear regression).  [You can see an example here.](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/LinearRegression)  If you want a polynomial that passes through *all* points, you can use the same code, but change the order of polyfit from 1 to 217.  I recommend SciPy instead of different packages because it does not require you to purchase a license.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend Excel. Use your point data to make a chart. Then right-click on the graph, and choose "Add Trendline". A dialog appears that lets you fit several different types of curves to your data. One of the options is a polynomial curve, with degree of at most 6.

If you need the equation of the fitted curve, then the dialog also has a check-box for "show equation on chart", which does what it says.

By default, the displayed equation will show the coefficients accurate to 4 decimal places, which may not be good enough for you. If so, right-click on the displayed equation, and choose Format Trendline Label. A dialog appears that lets you change the number of decimal places displayed. Then you can copy/paste this equation to anyplace you want.

The functions are simple, but, if necessary, you can find many tutorials showing you how to use them.

Comment: There is an option to shoe the equation on the chart. I don't know how to get the coefficients directly, without copying and retuning, which introduces some error

Comment: @Ross -- see info I added. There will be some error (as in any Excel calculation). But you should get 13 or 14 good digits, which is enough for most purposes.

Comment: @Ross -- also, I don't know what you mean by "retuning". Typo? Did you mean "retyping"?

Comment: Yes, that was supposed to be retyping.  I have a strong belief that no number that has been in a computer should be typed back into one-it should be transferred electronically.  In this case, you will lose precision as not all the decimals are displayed.  You are correct that double precision is good enough much of the time, but the polynomials that come out sometimes have delicate cancellations.  It helps to center your data on zero by subtracting the mean.

Comment: @Ross -- I agree that retyping anything is bad. The copy/paste technique I mentioned will give you all the precision that Excel has (double precision), which is the same as you'd get from any naive numerical approach. AFAIK, the best way to improve numerical stability is to use a different polynomial basis (like Bernstein of Chebyshev), not the power basis.

Comment: I hadn't seen the control for decimal places displayed.  I agree on both your points.

Comment: If you need the actual coefficients for further calculations,  or if you want things like the R^2 and so forth, you use the =LINEST() array function in Excel.  Google for details.

Answer (score 1):

If all 218 point line on one line, then choose any two points and apply the slope formula to find an equation for that line:

$$m = \frac{y_0 - y_1}{x_0 - x_1}$$

Then the line is of the form:

$$y = mx + c$$

Pluging any value for $y$ and $x$ you'll be able to obtain $c$.

If they don't lie on a line and if you want an exact polynomial-like functiona thata passes through all points, then do interpolation. I recommend Lagrange interpolation (polynomial), but you must be careful, because it works under specific condition. If the points don't satisfy those conditions, then try another type of interpolation.

And if you want just a good aproximizaton, then you can try the method of **least squares**. You can get a linear aproximization or a formula, depending of the type you choos.